# Object literal values and React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object-literal

Lets say there are 2 components Main and Card, Card is child of Main in React.js.
Card will pass in an string value to Main. Thus state in Main for the Card would update.

```
var Card= React.createClass({
...
this.props.updateName(loginVal.value); //pass in a 'string' to updateName()
...
});

var Main = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            names: []
        };
    },
    updateName: function (loginVal) {
        this.setState({ 
            names: this.state.names.concat(loginVal) // I don't understand why using 'concat' works but not 'push'.
        });
    },
    render: function(){
        var cardArr = this.state.names.map(function(item){
            return ( <Card login={item} /> );
        });
        return (
            <div>
                <Form updateName={this.updateName} />
                {cardArr}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

My question is why `this.state.names.concat(loginVal)` works when `this.state.names` is an `empty array` and `loginVal` is a `string`. `[].concat('string')` just don't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) adds the provided element(s) and returns the new length of the array, so `this.state.names` would be a number.

[`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) adds the provided element(s) to a new array and returns it, so `this.state.names` would be an array with the new name added.

Comment: I still don't understand. Would you explain it in a different way? I understand push updates original array and concat returns a new array. but I don't understand is why [].concat('string') here? I know my logic must be wrong somewhere.

Comment: I think it's very understandable what he wrote. You should write: `var names = this.state.names; names.push(loginVal); this.setState({ names: names });`

Comment: @user2734550 Whoever wrote the code probably just did it to be shorter. Both `this.state.names.push(loginVal); this.setState({names: this.state.names});` and `this.setState({names: this.state.names.concat(loginVal)});` do the same thing, one is just shorter than the other.

Comment: A big fundamental mistake... forgot push returns length. Thanks everyone.

Comment: `this.state.names.push(loginVal)` has the downside of mutating the array. In React, using mutative methods like push is discouraged as it makes it impossible to compare two snapshots of your component's props and state. See [shouldComponentUpdate](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) for example.

Comment: @Morhaus, would this <code>newNames=this.state.names; newNames.push(loginVal); setState({names: newNames}) </code> solve the vituralDOM diff's problem?

Answer (score 1):

`[].concat(["string", "other string")` will push each value to an new empty array. You can also pass a simple string instead of an array because the method was overwritten to make it more flexible.

`push("string")` do not work because it will return the new length of the array. But it will change the array instead of creating a new one.

you could use this:

```
this.state.names.push(value);
this.setState({
    names: this.state.names
});
```

Comment: Are you saying if it is NOT empty array, it would return new array. Otherwise, it doesn't?

Comment: Now that make sense. I wonder when they overwritten that, didn't know array can concat string directly

Comment: thats the power of JavaScript/functional programming. ;-)